# Resolving a macports installation 'conflict'

Tags: 64-bit, wxpython, wxwidgets, conflict, macports

I'm trying to build a 64-bit version of wxpython, to work with my macports version of python2.7 (universal build). I've been pointed to the following port `py27-wxpython-devel` and done the usual install command. Unfortunately I immediately receive the following error message

`Unable to execute port: Can't install wxWidgets-devel because conflicting ports are installed: wxWidgets`

I assume this means I need  to remove `wxwidgets` to enable me to install this port. I'm reluctant to do this however because I expect this `wxwidgets` is something to do with the version of `wxpython` that I currently have working. Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 16):

In this case, `wxwidgets-devel` is a newer, experimental version of the `wxwidgets` port.  You need to choose one or the other.  Fortunately, MacPorts makes it easy to do so with little risk.  First, run

```
sudo port deactivate wxwidgets
```

which will remove the installed links to the port but will not remove the built port.  Then you can run

```
sudo port install wxwidgets-devel
```

If you later want to switch back, just run:

```
 sudo port deactivate wxwidgets-devel
 sudo port activate wxwidgets
```

To permanently remove a port, use `uninstall`:

```
 sudo port uninstall wxwidgets
```

Comment: Thanks ned. Deactivated with no problems. `py27-wxpython-devel` install failed however. I think the salient parts of the error message are as follows:                                      `info:build error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1`
`:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py27-wxpython-devel/py27-wxpython-devel/work/wxPython-src-2.9.2.1/wxPython" && /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 setup.py --no-user-cfg build " returned error 1`

Comment: I replaced macports with homebrew today because of those conflicts. All other systems let me install development packages without conflicts. And then I thought macports cannot be that bad. So I found this question. The use of "-devel" for newer versions is a poor and confusing choice, but I guess it's an old tradition that's hard to change.